# defernumbers causes wrong indentation

Tags: biblatex, biber

## Addendum 2:

This has been fixed in the latest 3.0 dev version. Thank you, PLK!

## Addendum:

This question will probably be closed because it is to do with a development version of `biblatex` 3.0. For those interested, the issue can be found on the `biblatex` bug tracker [here](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/239).

---

`biblatex`'s `defernumbers=true` causes the bibliography to be typeset with wrong indentation.

## `defernumbers=false`

[image: defernumbers=false output]

## `defernumbers=true`

[image: defernumbers=true output]

Have a look at citation [1](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/239). It seems to that the spacing that should be reserved for the label is not passed on when `defernumbers` is enabled.

## MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@Article{gob,
  title           = {I've Made a Huge Mistake},
  author          = {Bluth, Gob},
  journal         = {Journal of Magicians},
  year            = {2003},
  volume          = {1},
  number          = {1},
  pages           = {1--10},
}

@Article{michael,
  title           = {Her?},
  author          = {Bluth, Michael},
  journal         = {Sudden Valley},
  year            = {2003},
  volume          = {1},
  number          = {1},
  pages           = {1--10},
}

@Article{tobias,
  title           = {Never-nudism},
  author          = {F{\"u}nke, Tobias},
  journal         = {Blue Man Group},
  year            = {2003},
  volume          = {1},
  number          = {1},
  pages           = {1--10},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
  backend=biber,
  defernumbers=true, % Should be enabled when using refsegments.
  refsegment=section,
  style=numeric,
] {biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{First section}
Check this out~\cite{gob}.
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,segment=1,]

\section{Second section}
Check this out~\cite{michael}.
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,segment=2,]

\nocite{tobias}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can confirm this behaviour with `biblatex` 2.9/Biber 1.9. As this seem very much like a bug to me, I would suggest you bring this up at the [`biblatex` bugtracker](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues).

Comment: @moewe PLK will either kill me, or get rid of `defernumbers` the way this is going. `:-)` Since PLK is generally active here, I'll not move the questions to the bug tracker for a couple of days.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a bug to me, you can fix this with

```
\makeatletter
\def\blx@bbl@labelnumber{%
  % Used at endentry, when reading .bbl
  % only do this for the global sorting list otherwise we increment
  % the labelnumbers for each sortlist
  \ifdefstrequal{\blx@slist@scheme}{\blx@sorting}
    {\ifdefempty\abx@field@localnumber
      {}% only if omitnumbers=true
      {\ifundef\abx@field@shorthand
        {%\iftoggle{blx@defernumbers}
         % {}% only if defernumbers=true
          {\csnumgdef{blx@labelnumber@\the\c@refsection}{%
              \csuse{blx@labelnumber@\the\c@refsection}+1}%
           \edef\abx@field@localnumber{%
              \csuse{blx@labelnumber@\the\c@refsection}}%
           \blx@bbl@fieldedef{labelnumber}{\abx@field@localnumber}%
         \iftoggle{blx@skipbib}
           {}
           {\blx@setlabwidth{\labelnumberwidth}{%
              \csuse{abx@ffd@*@labelnumberwidth}{%
                \ifdef\abx@field@prefixnumber
                  {\csuse{abx@ffd@*@prefixnumber}{\abx@field@prefixnumber}}
                  {}%
                \abx@field@localnumber}}}}}
        {\csgappto\blx@bbl@data{\let\abx@field@labelnumber\abx@field@shorthand}%
         \iftoggle{blx@skipbib}
           {}
           {\blx@setlabwidth{\labelnumberwidth}{%
              \csuse{abx@ffd@*@labelnumberwidth}{\abx@field@shorthand}}}}}}
   {}}
\makeatother
```

in the meantime.

It is just a re-arrangement of the standard order in `biblatex2.sty`.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@Article{gob,
  title           = {I've Made a Huge Mistake},
  author          = {Bluth, Gob},
  journal         = {Journal of Magicians},
  year            = {2003},
  volume          = {1},
  number          = {1},
  pages           = {1--10},
}

@Article{michael,
  title           = {Her?},
  author          = {Bluth, Michael},
  journal         = {Sudden Valley},
  year            = {2003},
  volume          = {1},
  number          = {1},
  pages           = {1--10},
}

@Article{tobias,
  title           = {Never-nudism},
  author          = {F{\"u}nke, Tobias},
  journal         = {Blue Man Group},
  year            = {2003},
  volume          = {1},
  number          = {1},
  pages           = {1--10},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
  backend=biber,
  defernumbers=true, % Should be enabled when using refsegments.
  refsegment=section,
  style=numeric,
] {biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\makeatletter
\def\blx@bbl@labelnumber{%
  % Used at endentry, when reading .bbl
  % only do this for the global sorting list otherwise we increment
  % the labelnumbers for each sortlist
  \ifdefstrequal{\blx@slist@scheme}{\blx@sorting}
    {\ifdefempty\abx@field@localnumber
      {}% only if omitnumbers=true
      {\ifundef\abx@field@shorthand
        {%\iftoggle{blx@defernumbers}
         % {}% only if defernumbers=true
          {\csnumgdef{blx@labelnumber@\the\c@refsection}{%
              \csuse{blx@labelnumber@\the\c@refsection}+1}%
           \edef\abx@field@localnumber{%
              \csuse{blx@labelnumber@\the\c@refsection}}%
           \blx@bbl@fieldedef{labelnumber}{\abx@field@localnumber}%
         \iftoggle{blx@skipbib}
           {}
           {\blx@setlabwidth{\labelnumberwidth}{%
              \csuse{abx@ffd@*@labelnumberwidth}{%
                \ifdef\abx@field@prefixnumber
                  {\csuse{abx@ffd@*@prefixnumber}{\abx@field@prefixnumber}}
                  {}%
                \abx@field@localnumber}}}}}
        {\csgappto\blx@bbl@data{\let\abx@field@labelnumber\abx@field@shorthand}%
         \iftoggle{blx@skipbib}
           {}
           {\blx@setlabwidth{\labelnumberwidth}{%
              \csuse{abx@ffd@*@labelnumberwidth}{\abx@field@shorthand}}}}}}
   {}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{First section}
Check this out~\cite{gob}.
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,segment=1,]

\section{Second section}
Check this out~\cite{michael}.
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,segment=2,]

\nocite{tobias}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but this won't compile for me: `! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...xnumber }} {}\abx@field@localnumber 
                                                  
l.40     \endentry`

Comment: Yes, I copied your solution code as is. The pre-`biber` `pdflatex` invocation works fine, the `biber` invocation also reports no errors. When I re-run `pdflatex` I get the error posted above.

Comment: @sudosensei I'm sorry, I seem to have messed up the code I posted here, it did not work for me either. Try the new code please.

Comment: Ah, yes! It compiles now. But it re-introduces the wrong numbering issue that was fixed in `biblatex` 3.0. Mine even starts from 4! But definitely +1 for solving the actual issue. I'll not mark this as accepted just yet though.

Comment: @sudosensei I noticed that my numbering now starts at "6". This is certainly something for the maintainers to have a look at.

Comment: It's like a random number generator! `:-)` You're absolutely right. I'll post the issue on the bug tracker instead. I wasn't aware of the `no-development-version-issues` rule. Thanks for all your help and patience.

Comment: @sudosensei I hope I was not implying there is such a rule (as I'm not sure on the status of such questions), but I'm only using the stable version. But the issues you have here are really more bugs reports than the normal questions here.

Comment: Marco Daniel voted for the other question to be closed on "development version" grounds, and this question is also related to the development version of `biblatex`. And like you said, there is a good chance that these are actual bugs that should be reported on the bug tracker.

Comment: I'm not sure there is such a 'rule', but I don't disagree with the closing. You could ask on [Meta](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/) if you'd like a discussion about it. I think there have been some related questions before (relating to bug reports especially), so perhaps a search will turn up something interesting.